# Database for many, tables for creator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm fairly proficient in normal SQL querying, but when it comes to administration, I'm not very far along.

I need a database that several users (users = logins I suppose) have access to. In that database, anyone of these users can create tables, but I only want the creator to get any (and full) access to that table. Is this hard to make work?

I work with MS SQL Server 2012.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to better describe the permissions that you want.  Can the creator drop the table?  Select from it?  Update it?  Delete rows?  Can one user see another user's tables?  What does "full access" mean?

Comment: I think you would be better off with separate databases for each user.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: The creator should have full access to do whatever he wants (except dropping the table as long as another user has access). Users will mostly need read access, since the tables (projects) are kind of static. (Project might be a bad word, but that word has been used for a while in an older implementation). The plan is to make this database a "project pool" where all users store projects. Some projects have overlapping users.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Users have separate databases as well, which act as holders of project groups. The project groups in turn contain links to projects. And since more than one user might need access to the same project (which is a table in the common database), I need that common base :) Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: Perhaps It's worth mentioning that this is part of a C# application.

Comment: Are all these tables that users can create going to be the same? ie same columns, same constraints?

Comment: In sql server, you can query tables in database x from database y.  I think separate databases is the best way to achieve your aim.

Comment: @Sasfrog: Likely, yes!

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: But that would require the server to search all databases for a table of a certain name. Wouldn't that pose a new problem?

Answer (score 0):

When the user connects, set up a schema for them, grant them full control over their own schema and give them create permissions so they can do what they like in their own schema, if you keep all users in their own schema, they won't be able to interfere with another user's schema unless you give them the rights to do so.